# How to change modification dates uptill a certain date?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, find

I want to copy the modification dates from my backup to my newly created server (forgot to specify the `-p` option on `cp`). As I changed files since I made the copy I only want to have the modification date changed uptill 31 days ago. To copy modification dates I [found](https://serverfault.com/questions/344731/rsync-copying-over-timestamps-only):

```
rsync -vrt --size-only /src /dest
```

I could not find rsync arguments to copy uptill a certain time so [another search got me](https://serverfault.com/questions/538767/how-to-rsync-files-folders-from-a-specific-date-forward):

```
rsync --progress --files-from=<(find /src_path -mtime -3 -type f -exec basename {} \;) /src_path/ /dst_path
```

I tried to figure out the behavior of the `-mtime` argument of `find`. To get what I *don't* want I must specify:

```
find . -mtime -31
```

In that way I get the files changed *since* 31 days ago but I just want to have the files till 31 days ago. Specifying a positive number does not help. Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `find . -mtime +31` (look up -mtime and -atime in the man page for find).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!